# Bubblesorting Calendars

Tags: java, sorting, calendar, bubble-sort

I'm having a bit of trouble bubblesorting `Calendar`s by date, I'm not sure what's wrong with my code.

First: I have a class(named `Note`) which contains multiple variables and methods, one of those variables is a `Calendar`.

Then I have an `ArrayList<aboveclass>` named `list` containing multiple instances of the above class. I'm trying to sort `list` by the date of each class instance.

This is my code:

```
for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){
    for(int x=0; x < list.size() - x - 1; x++){
        if(list.get(x).date.after(list.get(x+1).date)){
            Note temp = list.get(x);
            list.set(x, list.get(x+1));
            list.set(x+1,  temp);
            System.out.println(i + " and " + x + " Switched");
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing is being sorted though, and that `System.out.println` is never going. I have also tried switching `.after` with `.before` with no differences.

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Is the assignment explicitly to use bubble-sort by hand or could you simply use a `Comparator` ?

Comment: I can sort these however I'd like. I've never heard of a comparator, will itmake sorting these easier? If you post it in an answer I'll mark it best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need to sort your list by a bubble sort, then you can use `java.util.Collection.sort()`.

Your code will become :

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

You need however to make Your class (`Note` if I am right) implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) or to create a [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/) you can find some examples.

Comment: This worked.I had to look online how to use `Collections.sort` because your example doesn't show how to modify what you're sorting by, but it's working now

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `Comparator` for your `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<Note> x = new ArrayList<>();

x.sort(new Comparator<Note>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Note o1, Note o2) {
        return o1.date.after(o2.date);
    }
});
```

Something along those lines should work, I wasn't sure how you access the `date` variable.

Edit: The above version works only for Java 8.

Use this for Java 7 and earlier.

```
ArrayList<Entity> x = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.sort(x, new Comparator<Entity>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Entity o1, Entity o2) {
            return o1.date.after(o2.date);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `sort` isn't an avaliable method for an ArrayList, am I missing something?

Comment: That is a Java 8 feature. I will edit with code that runs on earlier Java versions.

Answer (score 0):

First, solution for your problems, in your algorithm you have problems in second loop
`for(int x=0; x < list.size() - x - 1; x++)` what are you doing is you are checking is `x<list.size()- x-1` what you supposed to do is  checking `x<list.size()- i-1` as each itteratation outer loop decrease number itterations of inner loop

second thing, is do as other people suggest, and sort your list by using `Collections.sort()` there is no point to reinvent wheel. Alternatively you could use `PriorityQueue` instead list, so your data will be always sorted